# is Microsoft Dynamcis CRM developed in .net ? can I use my .net skills for development in CRM

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, dynamics-crm

I am a .net developer and want to learn about Dynamics CRM. Please guide me on two things.

In what technology CRM is developed (in core) ? is it .net/asp.net ?

How .net skills can helpful in it ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer yes, MS CRM is based on .net framework. It exposes all its APIs through .net web services. You can develop workflows based on workflow foundation. You can develop extended functionality in ASP.Net and plug it into MS CRM Application.

If you are an existing .net developer you will find yourself at home.

Answer (score 1):

CRM is indeed written in .NET and its extensibility points are .NET based as well. I'm not sure what other information to provide based on your question.